# Rare when referred to meat not cooked for very long

Tags: meaning, terminology

According to the online Cambridge dictionary, *rare* when referred to meat means "not cooked for very long and still red".

As a native speaker of a Romance language I clearly understand the other meaning of *rare*, that is "uncommon", I'd like to know why *rare* is also employed to describe *a not cooked for long* piece of meat…

Comment: ***Rare***: “undercooked," 1650s, variant of Middle English rere, from Old English hrere "lightly cooked,". https://www.etymonline.com/word/rare - see also ***“Rare and Medium Rare”*** https://blog.oup.com/2009/12/rare-and-medium-rare/

Answer (score 6):

“Rare” (meaning “uncommon”) and “rare” (meaning “undercooked”) are actually two different words that nowadays happen to have the same spelling and pronunciation. The first “rare” [1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158248?rskey=DFWykY&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) stems from Latin “rarus” and has cognates in most Romance languages. The second “rare” [2](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158249?rskey=DFWykY&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) is of Germanic origin, and used to be written “rere”, “rear” etc in the (distant) past.

Comment: Hello, Marcos. This is basic research, and it is required that it accompanies the **question** on ELU. Also, answers to valid questions should be backed by supporting references, linked and attributed.

Comment: @EdwinAshword I get your point! I`ll keep that in mind in future.

Comment: @EdwinAshword I guess I should delete my answer, as your comment provides more pertinent information. On the other hand... It won't happen again!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Marcos is not answering his own question here, so it is not his responsibility to include the information in the question. BTW, “it is required that it accompanies the question” sounds ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @Xanne - (What would be the grammatical version of that? I'm wondering...)

Comment: @Sphinx— I don't think it's ungrammatical per se, though the subjunctive _it accompany_ sounds a touch better.

Comment: @Sphinx— Cambridge says _a touch_ means _slightly._ So yes, _a touch_ is an adverb phrase modifying _better._

Comment: @Xanne {'[T]his site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just opinion. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do ..... Thanks!' –  Sven Yargs} (I've many others). // We had the '_mandative subjunctive_' v _indicative_ v _periphrastic 'should'_ debate many years ago on ELU. As per CGEL, all are grammatical choices. //// The question is easily answered by basic research. Why aren't you chiding non-CVers?